# Degree of 2-variable real polynomial that’s large on a square and small on a nearby “L”

Tags: approximation-theory

I’d like to know what’s the minimum possible total degree of a real polynomial $p(x,y)$ such that:

(1) $p(x,y)\in [0,1]$ whenever $x,y\in [0,1]$ with either $x$ or $y$ at most $\epsilon$, and

(2) $p(x,y)\ge 2$ whenever $x,y\in [2\epsilon, 1]$,

in terms of $\epsilon$.  In particular, if any such polynomial must have degree $1/\epsilon^{\Omega(1)}$, then that has an interesting implication for quantum algorithms.  But right now I lack even a clear intuition as to what the right bound should be.

**Update:** In case it's helpful, it's not hard to give an upper bound of the form $O(1/\sqrt{\epsilon})$, indeed by a polynomial of the form $p(x,y)=q(x)r(y)$ where $q$ and $r$ are obtained from Chebyshev polynomials.  On the other hand, I believe one only gets a constant lower bound from considering any affine line through the $x,y$ plane.